# How to browse profiles on my social network?

Tags: php

In my social network I am stumped. i have built a pretty decent one but the ability to browse profiles by using their name (http://www.theqlick.com/usernamehere) to view their profile.

So people post on someone's virtual pinboard and in return are able to view their profile by clicking on them and their profile pops up, like on Facebook. But i am redirected to no url, i don't see what is wrong and can anyone suggest what is wrong and how i should do it?

My code is below:

```
  <?
  $getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to='$username' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $body = $row['body'];   
                    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                    $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                    $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];  

                                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$added_by'");
                                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                                             $profilepic_info = "./img/default_pic.jpg";
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                             $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
                                            }


                    echo "
                                            <div style='float: left;'>
                                            <img src='$profilepic_info' height='60'>
                                            </div>
                    <div class='posted_by'>
                    Posted by:
                                            <a href='$added_by'>$added_by</a> on $date_added</div>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <div  style='max-width: 600px;'>
                                            $body<br /><p /><p />
                                            </div>
                                            <hr />
                    ";
```

}

Comment: You have SQL injection and possible XSS/XSRF

Comment: What do you mean by "But i am redirected to no url, i don't see what is wrong and can anyone suggest what is wrong and how i should do it?"? Are you taken to a 404 page?  What does the URL display when you do it? etc.

Comment: yeah i am taken to a 404 page that the url cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod_rewrite` such as...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

within a `.htacess` file on your server.  Change `profile.php` to the script that you use to actually pull up the profile.  The 3 lines after `RewriteEngine On` check to make sure that the accessed file isn't a link, directory, or file.  It will rewrite everything else to `profile.php`.  Though, I highly suggest using a more structured URI scheme instead of `/profilenamehere` to something like `/profile/username`.  For that, change the last `RewriteRule` to `RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-zA-Z]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]`